# Wordpress Mobile Menu

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, menu

I took over a WordPress website that is using WPBakery Builder with theme Eis.
The menu is perfect on desktop, but in mobile view, everything is in lowercase.
I do not have the separate mobile menu option so it cannot be adjusted there.

How do I change the menu from lowercase to uppercase without implementing a separate plugin?

My CSS knowledge is limited, but with guidance, I can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can add css style to change to uppercase like below.

@media (max-width: 991px){.menu ul li{text-transform:uppercase;}}